# How does one best use a listener with ANTLR4 without the code getting messy?

Tags: antlr4

I'm using Antlr4 to parse a grammar and generate bytecode using a listener. Things started to get a bit complex when I implemented my first IF-ELSE-ENDIF set of instructions because I had to be sure to maintain stacks of context information to handle things such as nested ID statements and their scopes.

Now, I'm getting ready to handle multiple conditions combined in an IF such that I stop evaluating as soon as I encounter a condition that evaluates to false. The issue is that I'm noticing that my code is getting complex and hard to understand. I can barely keep track of it as it is and would pity anyone else looking at it. This is because I find that I have to set flags and context information on parent nodes to let the child nodes know what to do with the results they produce from their evaluation.

I thought of a few possibilities that could simplify things:

1) Use the listener to do nothing more than build a customized tree with important information that I need along the way so that I can then walk backward and forward as I see fit on that tree. Walking such a tree would make my code less messy because the context information I'm keeping in my tree nodes would replace the information I currently keep in stacks and structures everywhere.

2) Create multiple listeners each with a specific focus; i.e, code blocks inside IF and ELSE enclosures, multiple conditionals evaluation, etc. The idea is that as I traverse the main listener, I call a specialty listener with my code input (everything inside the IF block, for example), and get back information I can then use as I continue to generate my instructions.

3) Review how I'm doing things - maybe things are messy because I'm using the listener wrong. Hell, maybe I need to go ahead and use a Visitor instead.

I realize I could solve some of these issues with actions. I may resort to that if there is no other choice, but I'm trying to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Its hard to say what is to be done when neither the purpose of your language is know, nor the grammar, nor the code. I suspect that you use the listener to directly interpret your language. This is possible but usually the visitor/listener is used to transform the language into an intermediate language which is much easier to interpret.